# Google play publishing - how to speed up publishing of new app releases

Tags: android, publishing, google-play

I just published a new release of an android app on google play yet it seems to take ages for it to appear for the users of the google play store. In the developer console it is immediately updated so I assume all is okay with the apk. Taking ages means for me right now over one hour. Is this normal and if so, is there a way to speed up the process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's normal, and no, you can't speed it up. It's just the time it takes to  propagate the new information across all of Google's servers.

Comment: okay thx - what average time should i expect? Just new to publishing on google play, kind of painful when an urgent bug fix should go out ...

Comment: Normally a few hours, in my experience.

Comment: okay it finally appeared after a few hours so the situation is just as you described - thx

Comment: just tested it, it took less than hour to publish new apk

Answer (score 3):

This is for updating.
I just released a new APK as the initial Beta release(V1.0) and it took almost 6 days to publish in the Play Store for Open Testing. (**01.09.2020** to **06.09.2020**).
After that, I released V1.1 and it was published within 28 minutes. (**06.09.2020**)